# Mongolite: How to insert Date in mongodb using r

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

Hi I'm trying insert date but it is only taking as string.

```
mongo$update(query = paste0('{"_id": ', c, ' }'),
update = paste0('{"$addToSet": {"values": {date_data": "ISODate("',dat,'")"
} } }'))
```

If i remove quotes from value: "ISODate("',dat,'")", its is giving invalid json object error and with quote it inserts as string.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert date in mongodb using rmongolite package use $date.

```
mongo$update(
    query = paste0('{"_id": ', c, ' }'),  
    update = paste0('{"$addToSet":  
        {"values":{"date_data":{"$date":"', dat, '"} } }'
    )
)
```